# Android app "unfortunately stop"s while running. The error is no activity found to handle intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, bluetooth, manifest

I am new to android. I am trying to build an app which makes my device's bluetooth discover able.
And in these block of codes :

```
public void bTEnableDisable_Discoverable(){
    Intent discoverIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED);
    //discoverIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION,300);
    startActivity(discoverIntent);
    Log.d(TAG,"scan mode");

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver2,intentFilter);
}
```

I got this error :

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.bluetooth.adapter.action.SCAN_MODE_CHANGED }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED` is not used by activities. It is used for system broadcasts. Your `IntentFilter` and `registerReceiver()` is using this action properly. You cannot use it with an `Intent` and `startActivity()`, though, as your first lines of code attempt to do.

Try `ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE` for starting an activity to allow the user to allow for Bluetooth discovery.

Comment: Thanks.. It worked as i changed it to ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE